# Depth of Field in iOS12 beta broken?

Tags: ios, arkit, ios12

I'm recieving an error when enabling Depth of Field with iOS12.  Didn't have this error with iOS11.

`` validateComputeFunctionArguments:843: failed assertion `Compute Function(downsample_4x_dof): missing buffer binding at index 1 for outbuf[0].' ``

Comment: Just getting back to this question of mine, what I find is inconsistency to blur out the background camera image. I have yet to determine why, Is suspect it could be to do with the thermal throttling of the hardware. Yet to find any fool proof solution.